# Nuxtjs VueMeta css order

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-meta

I am currently loading a main stylesheet via the `css` prop within the `nuxt.config.js` I wish to load in some other styles to overwrite some of those in the main css.

I would like to be able to define those within the `head()` of a layout so that I can add the styles dynamically like so:

```
head () {
  const style = [
    { cssText: this.customStyles, type: 'text/css' }
  ]

  return {
    style
  }
}
```

But this always loads before the main styles are added and as such are not being used to overwrite the styles.

I tried to set the style to be injected into the `body` but that does not work either.

Maybe I need to compile the `sass` separately and then include it as a file in the above `head()` tag.

Does anyone have any insight to how I might achieve this without having to have a separate build process?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to overwrite the main css, and not just changing the main css to what you want? Having external, internal, and inline css is very sloppy for your markup.

Comment: @ChrisHitchcock It's a requirement for the app to allow users to override certain styles with their own.